# How to sort frequencies in CreateTableOne

Tags: r

Here is a representation of my dataset

```
mydata<-data.frame(ID=1:37,var=c(rep("A",12),rep("B",8),rep("C",17)))
```

I calculated the frequency of each modality of the variable `var`

```
library(tableone)

CreateTableOne(data = mydata["var"])
```

What I want is to sort the frequencies in decreasing way, like below:

```
          Overall   
  n       37        
  var (%)        
     C    17 (45.9)    
     A    12 (32.4) 
     B     8 (21.6)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the factor levels to be in decreasing order of frequency.

```
library(tableone)

mydata2 <- transform(mydata, var = factor(var, names(sort(-table(var)))))
CreateTableOne("var", data = mydata2)
```

giving:

```
          Overall   
  n       37        
  var (%)           
     C    17 (45.9) 
     A    12 (32.4) 
     B     8 (21.6)
```

Comment: Any suggestions for doing this with a dplyr tibble?